# JavaScript Parsing Nested JSON Arrray

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have the following JSON.

It is the coordonates of differents points (x,y,w,h).
I need to parse this JSON with hashmap? Array? Will need coordinate for each point to use later.

How can I proceed?

```
{ "_id" : "543e95dddedd",
  "result" : [ [ "Point1",
        [ [ 22,
            32,
            444,
            4444
          ] ]
      ],
      [ "point2",
        [ [ 43,
            112,
            442,
            344
          ],
          [ 34,
            34,
            1246,
            44
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
}
```

With this, I can display the JSON correctly in "`points`":

```
app.get('/id/:id', function (req, res){
  return Coordonate.findById(req.params.id, function (err, points) {
    if (!err) {
      return res.send(points);
    } else {
      return console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: What is the result you expect ?

Comment: I would say an array with point and coordinates. or hashmap could be more efficient? point1 22 32 444 444, point2 43 112 442 344, point2 34 34 1246 44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your JSON is stored in `obj` variable.

```
var points = {}
for (var i in obj.result){
    var pointName =  obj.result[i][0];
    var coordinates = obj.result[i][1];
    points[pointName] = coordinates;
}

console.log(points);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's works fine but at the end I have a strange error like: [ 34,
            34,
            1246,
            44
          ]
        ],   undefined: undefined,
  r: 'e' }

Comment: Then, you did not show us the totallity of your JSON, it must contains weirds values after the ones you show us.